# ShortBuffer and matrix in Java

Tags: java, file, buffer

I have a problem with ShortBuffer. This is my code:

```
FileChannel fc = new FileInputStream("C:/Dane DMS/"+names2).getChannel();
ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect((int) fc.size());
while (bb.remaining() > 0) fc.read(bb);
fc.close();
bb.flip();
// choose the right endianness
ShortBuffer sb = bb.order(ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN).asShortBuffer();
```

In this file I have a matrix.

```
111 222 333 123
444 555 666 456
777 888 999 789
098 765 432 321
```

I need to change this matrix to:

```
098 765 432 321
777 888 999 789
444 555 666 456
111 222 333 123
```

I must change this matrix or create loop that will start from number 098 and end at number 123.

I doesn't print this matrix. I'm using:

```
for(int i = 0; i<=1200; i++)
                   {
                       for(int j = 0; j<=1200 ; j++)
                       {

                       }

                   }
```

to crossing matrix but in this way I start from number 111 and I need start from 098 and end at 123.

Comment: Where is the code you use to print the matrix, and what is the order of the elements in the matrix: left to right then top to bottom or a different one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this

```
FileChannel fc = new FileInputStream("C:/Dane DMS/"+names2).getChannel();
ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect((int) fc.size());
while (bb.remaining() > 0) fc.read(bb);
fc.close();
bb.flip();
// choose the right endianness
ShortBuffer sb = bb.order(ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN).asShortBuffer();

short[][] Matrix = new short[1201][1201];
for(int i = 0; i<=1200; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j<=1200 ; j++)
    {
        Matrix[1200-i][j] = sb.get(i*1201+j);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So you need to reverse the rows?  To do this you need to work out the row length. Then you can swap the first and last row, then the second last and second row etc.

Comment: hmmm, can you tell me how I can do this on this matrix? In reality this matrix will be 1201x1201.